# Error in Connection with Oracle Database using java

Tags: java

```
    System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Where is your Oracle Driver");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Oracle JDBC driver registered");
    try
    {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "scott",
                "ahsan");
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Your connection is faild Plz check database");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

And Giving Error with Connection to database
Your connection is faild Plz check database

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at database.main(database.java:30)
```

Comment: You have an oracle which is listen on localhost port 1521?

Comment: In  recent Java versions the `Class.forName(...)` shouldn't be necessary any more. But that has nothing to do with your problem. But are you really running an oracle database on your development machine?

Answer (score 0):

This may due to problem in network setup. Try disabling the firewall and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your Oracle listener is configured to listen on port 1521.
open the tnsname.ora or listener.ora to find which hostname(ip address) , what is port number and what is the SID which you are connecting.